# How does one invoke a runas admin in python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, elevated-privileges

I accidentally ended up asking a different question than I should have; so instead I'll ask again.

How would I run a subprocess that requests admin priveleges?

I've tried

```
subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:administrator', 'python', 'pathtoscript'])
```

But when I try that, as soon as I enter my admin password, the subprocess closes.

Also, how would I do what I am attempting on linux/max? It may be as simple as

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'python', 'pathtoscript'])
```

for linux, as well as mac's equivalent of sudo; but since I am having problems with windows alone I'm not so sure.

Comment: on linux `check_call(['sudo',"-S", 'python',  'pathtoscript'])`, you will then have to enter you password, you could automate it by using Popen and writing the password to stdin with a PIPE but your might not want your password stored in plain text, you could also just run the script with sudo

Comment: On Windows, if the script is meant to run on typical boxes, then it should assume the "Administrator" account is disabled and UAC is enabled. This means runas.exe cannot run a process as an administrator. Instead use ctypes or an extension module to call [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154) using the verb `"runas"`.